# Java: Accessing Subclass Methods from a Array of Parent objects

Tags: java, arrays, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to create a program that starts with a `Piece` class. For the purpose of the exercise every other class extends `Piece`. The other classes contain methods for moving the pieces, either one space or n spaces.

All of the pieces are stored in a 2D array which the use to move around.

My problem is that if i make an array of Pieces I cannot access the move methods as they are stored in the subclasses. I also can't just cast the object because i have 4 different types that the user can ask to move.

This is the code that adds a piece to the board

```
//adds a piece based on given type, but only if the space is clear (null)
public void addpiece(String type, String n, String c, int x, int y){
    if(board[x][y] == null){
        if(type == "FastFlexible"){
            board[x][y] = new FastFlexiblePiece(n,c,x,y);
        }
        else if(type == "FastPiece"){
            board[x][y] = new FastPiece(n,c,x,y);
        }
        else if(type == "SlowFlexible"){
            board[x][y] = new SlowFlexiblePiece(n,c,x,y);
        }
        else if(type == "SlowPiece"){
            board[x][y] = new SlowPiece(n,c,x,y);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invaild type");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code that tries to move the piece, the error I get is because the parent `Piece` doesn't have a move method, but I can't figure out a way to get the pieces to cast correctly

```
 //Move a piece, two method one for fast and one for slow
public void movePiece(int x, int y, String direction){
    if(board[x][y] != null){
        if(board[x][y].getType().equals("SlowPiece")){
            board[x][y] = board[x][y].move(direction);
        }
        else if(board[x][y].getType().equals("SlowFlexible")){
            board[x][y] = board[x][y].move(direction);
        }
    }
}
```

There is another similar method for fast pieces.

Constructor for the slowPiece:

```
//Constructor
public SlowPiece(String n, String c, int x, int y){
    super(n,c,x,y);
    this.setType("SlowPiece");
}
```

But the code doesn't notice what type any of the Pieces are and so I can't cast them correctly

Comment: Could you please show your class definitions ?

Comment: I didn't know about the instanceof keyword, that basically solves my problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very aim of [Polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) is to avoid writing code like the implementation specified for `public void movePiece(int x, int y, String direction){`.

board[x][y] can refer to SuperType Piece and any of its SubTypes like the SlowPiece, SlowFlexible, FastPiece, FastFlexible. Piece can have the abstract `move` behavior specified in the definition of the class, without having to provide the implementation. All the SubTypes of Piece class provide their own implementation for `move` method.

The method `public void movePiece(int x, int y, String direction)` would simply boil down to this :

```
    public void movePiece(int x, int y, String direction){ 
        board[x][y].move(direction);
    }
```

At runtime, `move` method is dynamically dispatched depending upon the SubType of Piece class.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add an [abstract method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) to the parent `Piece` class.

```
public class Piece{
    public abstract void move();
}
```

**NOTE:** now you can't directly instantiate a `Piece`. This code is illegal:

```
Piece p = new Piece();
```